# relative pronouns - subject and object used inside the same clause

Tags: relative-pronouns

I would really appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

> He invented a weapon that was so dangerous that no one dared to use (it).

I was certain that there is no need for **it** here but a friend of mine disagrees.
This is how I understood.

The first sentence (He invented a weapon) and the second one (the rest) are combined with the common element, **a weapon**. Thus, the initial **a weapon** stays and the second one gets replaced by **that**.
On a closer look, I think **that** works as a subject relative pronoun (It was so dangerous) and also works as a object relative pronoun (No one dared to use it).

My questions are:

> From the original sentence, which is grammatically correct, with or without it?

> In my opinion, in order to insert **it**, the sentence should be: He invented a weapon and it was so dangerous that no one dared to use it. Is this correct?

> Is it correct to use one pronoun as the both usage of subject and object inside the same adjective clause?

Thank you!

Comment: The only way to omit "it" would be to recast the sentence as _He invented a weapon that was (too) dangerous to use_.

Answer (score 3):

The word "it" is necessary in that sentence. In the construction "so X that Y", the "that" does not act as a relative pronoun at all. Y is always a clause on its own: in this case "no one dared to use it". The word "that" is not a part of the clause.

For that reason, sentences such as "the bread was so tasty that I had for breakfast" are ungrammatical.

EDIT: I misunderstood the original question. So to answer it: can the *first* occurrence of the word "that" in the original sentence act as both a subject relative pronoun and an object relative pronoun?

Theoretically, it could:

> He invented a weapon that was so dangerous that Y and [that] no one dared to use.

In the above, the second "that", which is in square brackets, is not necessary; so the first "that" can indeed play both roles simultaneously.

The problem with the original sentence is that it's not possible to parse "that no one dared to use" as part of the outer clause. Because "no one dared to use it" immediately follows "so X that", it can only be interpreted as the argument Y in "so X that Y". In that context, the clause has no relative pronoun introducing it and so has to explicitly include both subject and object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Actually the that I’m referring to is that as in … a weapon **that** was so … (I’m aware of the fact that **that** in the expression so … that … is not relative pronoun.) My question was if this **that** can work as a subject relative pronoun and object relative pronoun at the same time in the following clause. I’d like to know if that in this case can work as a subject relative pronoun in ‘was so dangerous’ and an object relative pronoun in ‘no one dared to use’ at the same time inside this clause.

Comment: oh! very interesting, I'll update my original answer

Comment: So the problem is that it is difficult to parse the last part with **that**! I understand now, thanks for the update!

Comment: Importantly, the expression _that no one dared to use it_ is an 'indirect complement' licensed by the "so" that modifies "dangerous".

Answer (score 0):

> *He invented a weapon that was so dangerous* [*that no one dared to use*
> (*it*)].

The verb "use" is transitive here, so in this case the object "it" is required.

The whole of the expression "that was so dangerous that no one dared to use it" is a relative clause with "weapon" as antecedent. The relative word functions as subject within the relative clause. But "that" is not an object relative pronoun; rather, it is a pro-form acting as object of "use" that refers to "weapon".

Note that the bracketed expression is called an 'indirect complement'. It is called this because although it is complement of the adjective "dangerous", it is licensed by the adverb "so" that modifies "dangerous". We know this because if we drop "so" the adjective phrase becomes ungrammatical.